# Perfect forwarding variadic templates of l-value ref and r-value ref and non-ref types?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

Im my program I have template classes that are mostly wrappers for a special purpose std::function<..>. The minimal example is:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Foo {

    public:

        explicit Foo(std::function<void(Args&&...)> _function)
            : function_(_function)
        {}

        template<typename... Arguments>
        void Bar(Arguments&&... _args) {
            function_(std::forward<Arguments>(_args)...);
        }

    private:

        std::function<void(Args&&...)> function_;

};
```

Instantiations of these templates are usually a combination of l-value ref, r-value ref or no-ref types. The problem is that calling Bar leeds to errors when some of the arguments are non-ref types such as an int or std::vector. The work around is to declare a temp variable and then move it into the function call.

```
int main(){
    Foo<int> test1([](int x) { });
    const int x = 1;
    test1.Bar(x); // [Error] cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'const int'

    int tmp = x;
    test1.Bar(tmp); // [Error] cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'
    test1.Bar(std::move(tmp)); // [OK] But I don't want to have to reassign and move every time I use this.

    /* I want perfect forwarding on variables that can be forwarded. */
    /* There are cases when the templates are like this with a combination of l-value ref and r-value ref and non-ref types. */
    Foo<const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&&, int> test2([](const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&&, int) { });
    test2.Bar(std::vector<uint8_t>(1, 2), std::vector<uint8_t>(1, 2), x); // [Error] cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'const int'

    return 1;
}
```

I want to be able to use Bar with any template parameter without having to re-assign and std::move() everytime, but also have ref parameters perfectly forwarded. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**
After looking around the web for a bit - The problem is `std::function<void(Args&&...)> function_;` is not a function that takes a universal ref but instead takes an r-val ref. So trying to forward no-ref types throws an error.

So the question then is, is it possible to have and store a std::function that takes a universals references?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155385/universal-reference-in-a-class-template Note that, in your case, `void Bar(...)` is not using universal reference

Comment: @Amadeus Opps! My bad with the MWE .Changed it to universal reference (erros are the same). I'll look at that link now see if it helps.

Comment: No, it's not possible to store `std::function` that takes universal references. Only a function template can take universal references, but `std::function::operator()` is not a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `std::function<void(Args&&...)>`, you actually expect r-value reference, you probably want `std::function<void(Args...)>`:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(std::function<void(Args...)> _function)
        : function_(_function)
    {}

    template <typename... Arguments>
    void Bar(Arguments&&... _args) {
        function_(std::forward<Arguments>(_args)...);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(Args...)> function_;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5832113f9d9d15c2)

If appropriate, you may get rid of `std::function`:

```
template <typename F>
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(F f) : f(f) {}

    template <typename... Ts>
    auto operator ()(Ts&&... args) const
    -> decltype(f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))
    {
        return f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

private:
    F f;
};

template <typename F>
Foo<F> MakeFoo(F f) { return Foo<F>{f}; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0804c4c7271f0a34)